# Map elements of a list of lists to a dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary

The problem is pretty straightforward, I have a dictionary in which I have the classes and a number assigned for identification, for example:

```
{'checkbox': 0,
 'radio': 1,
 'dropdown': 2,
 'listbox': 3,
 'button': 4,
 'link': 5,
 'input': 6,
 'label': 7}
```

The thing is, the list is composed by other list of different lengths that have these keys values, such as:

```
[['link',
'dropdown',
'dropdown',
 ['input', 'link'], ['input', 'button', 'link'],
 ['dropdown',
  'button'],...
```

It is very irregular since it is related to the bounding boxes annotations. So I aimed to use map function and list comprehensions.

```
# Simply using replace method -> know that, these list of labels is a dataframe column
labels_remapped = df['labels'].replace(Dict)

# Using map(Dictionary, iterable)
labels_remapped = map(Dict, df['labels'])

# Iterating over sublists
labels_remapped = [map(Dict, sublist) for sublist in labels]
```

However, I didn't succeeded. How can I iterate over this specific list and replace with its corresponding value?

Comment: Can you share example of code which you've tried?

Comment: The format of your list of lists is incorrect, can you please fix it?

Comment: What have you tried, exactly?

Comment: I've rolled back the recent edit because it assumed OP's data was structured a specific way, when I think it's not clear. I think OP is responsible for clarifying the structure of their data.

Comment: @ddejohn: I guess that makes sense. It _is_ hard to tell exactly what structure the OP was going for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursively process deeply into the data:

```
def deep_map(func, xs):
    if not isinstance(xs, list):
        return func(xs)
    return [deep_map(func, x) for x in xs]

deep_map(lambda x: d[x], xs)
```

...where `d` is a dict, and `xs` is your data.